# How to Import Sample Projects into Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to **import** [downloaded Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29) into `Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone`, as we do in `Eclipse`

Comment: :|  You download them, extract them, then open the solution file.  What's the problem?  Can you [edit] and expand on why you can't do this?

Comment: I am Currently doing the same, But when i Open the new Project the old one disappears, But in Eclipse it's not this way, is the SDK made to work like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't import them, in Visual Studio just go to *File->Open->Project/Solution* and open the `*.sln` from the downloaded sample files.

If you want to import it into an existing solution, right click on your solution in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, go to "Add" and choose *"Existing Project"* and navigate to the `*.csproj` file from the downloaded sample files.

Comment: I am Currently doing the same, But when i Open the new Project the old one disappears, But in Eclipse it's not this way, is the SDK made to work like this?

Comment: Then open one of your solutions/projects, and in the Solution Explorer right click the solution name and go to "Add" and choose "Existing Project" and navigate to the *.csproj file of the other project you want to open. Now you can have both open at the same time

Comment: The Solution Explorer is accessible by the View menu and if you don't see that you can add an "Existing Project", make sure you have that view open.